# How to select and deselect a marker in google maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a list of places which are marked in google maps using `Markers`. I want to select a `Marker` so that it will highlight with a different color. I have set it using `marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))`. When I click on the same marker or any other marker I want remove the selection made in the first marker and set it back to the default color.

```
 map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        aa= marker.getPosition().latitude;
         bb=marker.getPosition().longitude;
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

        }
```

According to the code above when i click on other markers the selection made in the first marker is still there, and it stays colored `HUE_BLUE`. How can I remove the modified color and transfer the selection to currently clicked marker?

Comment: You need to keep track of all markers in a LIST or something. Now when you click a new one check and remove previous ones.

Comment: Is the `InfoWindow` still showing for previously clicked markers?  Or is it strictly that the Marker stays colored blue?

Comment: @DanielNugent No infowindow changes according to selection..Yes the marker stays coloured blue so when i click the next marker the that marker turns blue

Comment: Try to add your each marker in list and when click to any marker first deselect all marker with list iteration and then apply selection clicked marker .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this and it works, just add a `Marker` reference as an instance variable in order to keep a reference of the last clicked `Marker`, and each time a new `Marker` is clicked, set the previous one back to the default color.

You can also check `!marker.equals(prevMarker)` before setting the `Marker` to `HUE_BLUE`, this will allow a subsequent click on the `Marker` to set the color back to the default color.

Instance variable:

```
Marker prevMarker;
```

Click Listener:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            aa= marker.getPosition().latitude;
            bb=marker.getPosition().longitude;
            if (prevMarker != null) {
                //Set prevMarker back to default color
                prevMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            //leave Marker default color if re-click current Marker
            if (!marker.equals(prevMarker)) {
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                prevMarker = marker;
            }
            prevMarker = marker;
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: I want to change the color comparing the response I will be getting from other class like following

  `if (marker.getSnippet().equals(currentEvent.getButton_one())) {
        response.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    } else response.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));`

Value of marker.getSnippet() is either Y or N, depends on the button user will press. I want to check this with currentEvent.getButton_one();, which gives value of 1st button. <continues in next comment>

Comment: Problem here is I am getting correct value of currentEvent.getButton_one() in other class where it is declared but not in CustomInfoWindow class.

Final condition should check like this:
if Y == Y  ---> GREEN else RED

Comment: @AtharvaPuranik, If you need help with your issue, open a new question and post your code, and I'll take a look!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707596/change-color-of-response-text-on-my-snippet-on-selecting-the-marker-in-android  @Daniel

Comment: @DanielNugent I have four markers with four different icons. If I click one It should be selected with a particular icon and If I click another marker then the previous one should be deselected and the current icon should be selected with its particular icon and so on. Could you please help me?