# OnMarkerClick within a loop

Tags: android, json, google-maps

While trying to develop a map app with multiple markers, that allows displaying a popup window with information when click on a marker ,I faced this problem when it comes to displaying the info (it has to be different info according to the loop order but it keeps demanding that the variables needs to be final ) but I keep having the same result for all popup windows (the last record's value) even if I make the variables global ,Sorry for my English and Please HELP.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if(broadcastReceiver == null){
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Response.Listener<String> responseListener =new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response== null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                             jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                              jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
                            int i=0 ;
                            int id,e;
                            Double lt,lg;
                            while (i<jsonArray.length()) {
                                 jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                e=  jo.getInt("etat");

                                id= jo.getInt("driver_id");

                                lt=jo.getDouble("latitude");

                                lg= jo.getDouble("longitude");


                                map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick( Marker marker) {
                                        if(marker.getTitle() != null){
                                            return true;
                                        }else{

                                            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);

                                            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 500,500,true);
                                            popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100,100);
                                            TextView tvNom= (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tvNom);

                                            tvNom.setText(id +"");

                                            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                                                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                                                    return true;
                                                }
                                            });


                                            return false;}
                                    }
                                });
                                if(e==0) {
                                    marker = markerMap.get(d);
                                    if (marker != null) {
                                        marker.remove();
                                        markerMap.remove(d);
                                    } else {
                                        markerMap.remove(d);
                                    }

                                }
                                else{


                                    if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {
                                        Intent intent= new Intent(MapActivity.this,InfoWindow.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("id",id+"");

                                        // Update the location.
                                        marker = markerMap.get(id);
                                        marker.remove();
                                        markerMap.remove(id); //added
                                        MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(new LatLng(lt,lg)).visible(true);
                                        marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                                        markerMap.put(id, marker);


                                    } else {

                                        MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(new LatLng(lt, lg)).visible(true);

                                        marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                                        markerMap.put(id, marker);



                                    }   }



                              i++;}


                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            AlertDialog.Builder nbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapActivity.this);
                            nbuilder.setMessage("Error")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    }

                }
            };
            RetrieveCoordinates retrieve = new RetrieveCoordinates ( responseListener );
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MapActivity.this);
            queue.add( retrieve);

        }
    };
}
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));

}
```

Comment: You should not be calling `map.setOnMarkerClickListener()` inside a loop.  You only need one listener, and it will be called for any Marker on the map that is clicked.  See here for a simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740839/how-to-select-and-deselect-a-marker-in-google-maps-in-android

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry I didn't get it , you're telling me not to use  map.setOnMarkerClickListener() but in the example you gave they are using it !

Comment: You still need to use it, but it should not be called inside a loop.

Comment: Would you please explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed out, all your listeners are added to the map object only. What the API provides for attaching different info on each marker object is a property called *tag*.

Use setTag(Object) on your marker object(s).

Wherever you've declared your markers, loop through them attaching your wanted tag:

```
for(int i=0; i < allMarkers.length; i++)
    marker.setTag();
```

And then assign listener like:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick( Marker marker) {
                                    if(marker.getTitle() != null){
                                        return true;
                                    }else{

                                        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);

                                        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 500,500,true);
                                        popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100,100);
                                        TextView tvNom= (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tvNom);
                                        //---------retrieve this marker's tag - could be Integer or any other Object.
                                        int id = (Integer)marker.getTag();

                                        tvNom.setText(id +"");

                                        container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                                                popupWindow.dismiss();
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        });


                                        return false;}
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: dev8080,  I tried what you said , but still got the same value too

Comment: See my edit. I assume you only want id in the inner class.

Comment: Ok, I'll let you know what I get

Comment: Well your idea seems brilliant and reasonable but for a non obvious reason I got the same result again , I guess that happens because we set the listener in the whole map, I mean there is no direct relation between the marker and the marker listener .

Comment: Well, that's the answer then....never looked at that coz I thought this is the loop-variable-cannot persist-in-inner-class sort of problem. But then why were you using a loop in the first place?

Comment: See the edit. I don't know how markers and ids are co-related in your case, so just gave you an outline and changed a line in your listener.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,major progress ! It shows the appropriate values , but after few clicks it crashes (FATAL EXCEPTION ,java.lang.NullPointerException ,internal calls) on line : int id =(Integer) marker.getTag (); knowing that I've put :marker.setTag (id);

Comment: dev8080 I used the loop to retrieve the data from jsonArray.

Comment: It works just fine now , I added a condition :if  (marker.getTag () !=null) .dev8080 seriously I can't thank you enough ,I spent days looking for a solution ,thanks a lot for your help :) :)