# How to select and deselect a marker in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a list of places which are marked in google maps using Markers. I want to select a Marker so that it will highlight with a different color. When I click on the same marker or any other marker I want remove the selection made in the first marker and set it back to the default color.

This is my onClusterItemClick method

```
override fun onClusterItemClick(p0: Station?): Boolean {
        dragView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        viewModel.loadStation(p0?.id!!)
        val marker = renderer.getMarker(p0)

        //save previous merker here

 marker?.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_pin_selected))

        return true
    }
```

This is my Station Renderer

```
/**
     * Class to design the pin point into the map
     */

    inner class StationRenderer(context: Context, map: GoogleMap,
                                clusterManager: ClusterManager<Station>) : DefaultClusterRenderer<Station>(context, map, clusterManager) {


        override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<Station>?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
            markerOptions?.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createStoreMarker(cluster?.size.toString())))
        }

        override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: Station?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
            markerOptions?.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_pin))
        }


        private fun createStoreMarker(stationsCount:String): Bitmap {
            val markerLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_item, null)
            val markerImage = markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_image) as ImageView
            val markerRating = markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_text) as TextView
            markerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_map_pin)
            markerRating.text = stationsCount
            markerLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
            markerLayout.layout(0, 0, markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight())
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            markerLayout.draw(canvas)
            return bitmap
        }


        override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<Station>?): Boolean {
            return cluster?.size !!> 1
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In googleMaps these is no such thing as selected or deselected or some kind of listeners specifically for that `but` you have `onMarkerClick();` you can use this Listener and add some logic to achieve that thing.

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker){
     return false;
   }
});
```

You can get the Idea from this: [How to select and deselect a marker in google maps in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740839/how-to-select-and-deselect-a-marker-in-google-maps-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: Im a using clusterItemClick, do you have anything for that?

Comment: Even in that case you will have to add your logic specifically in `onClusterItemClick` to save the previous marker and then on selecting some other marker Reset the first one

Comment: My question was about the logic :)

Comment: I checked it out before and I did not understand tjhe logic because prevMarker is a magic variable, so I dont know where it came from

Comment: `prevMarker` vairaible will  keep the reference to the previous just keep it `null` by default in start of activity and do the rest as it is

Comment: can you show an example using my code, I am really confused :S

Comment: are you getting the selected marker here at this line ? `val marker = renderer.getMarker(p0)`

Comment: I am glad to know that !

Comment: Just one more question, I want to clean the markers(put default background on it) if I touch the map, I am using onMapClick but how can I set the default icon on all the markers

Comment: same logic ! they way you are keeping the reference to the `prevMarker` take another `var` and then keep the selected marker reference too like this `selectedMarker =renderer.getMarker(p0)` `globally` and then when on `onMapClick` will be called then change the `selectedMarker ` color to default

Comment: Note: above scenario will work if at any given point only one marker is selected only.. if there are many then you will have to keep the track of each and do the reset on all

Comment: For some reason when I click the marker, click on other marker and came back to click on the first marker he will not get selected